# IBM WAS wsadmin update cluster app

Tags: websphere, jython

I wrote a jython script for updating an IBM WAS application server

```
AdminApp.update("MyEAR", "app", ["-appname", "MyEAR",
                "-target", "+WebSphere:" + cellName + "," + nodeName + "," + serverName,
                "-contents", "./MyEAR.ear",
                "-operation", "update"])
AdminConfig.save()
```

where cellName, nodeName and serverName are arg from command line.

SO the questions is: How can I update a cluster using Jython and AdminApp.update command ? What will be the difference between server and cluster update.

Comment: Are you trying to update the application contents while keeping the target the same?   Or are you trying to update the target?   What are you trying to update?

Comment: application contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to re-supply the **target** if you are only updating the *contents* of the application.

In general the [AdminApp.update()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html#rxml_taskoptions__cmd82) will merge "bindings" when using `-operation update`.

So something like this may be all you need:

```py
AdminApp.update("MyEAR", "app", ["-appname", "MyEAR",
                "-contents", "./MyEAR.ear",
                "-operation", "update"])
AdminConfig.save()
```

Note in that same link there are some other options like `update.ignore.new`, and `update.ignore.old` if you need different merging behavior.